# Achilles' mother used my kind

Tags: riddle

Who or what am I?

I look at the sky and my eyes reflect it
I can bring death but also life
Achilles' mother used my kind
My bed is smooth as sand itself
I can be kind and allow you to pass
When I am angry, you won't make it.

What am I?

Comment: The third hint makes the riddle a tad obvious.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are a

> river

I look at the sky and my eyes reflect it

> the surface of a river can reflect the sky

I can bring death but also life

> Rivers have life-giving water but can also kill people

Achilles' mother used my kind

> The river Styx that Achilles was dipped in

My bed is smooth as sand itself

> Riverbeds can be made of sand

I can be kind and allow you to pass /
When I am angry, you won't make it.

> Rivers can be gentle and fordable in some places/times, and too violent to cross at other places/times

Answer (score 8):

You are

> water

I look at the sky and my eyes reflect it

> You can see the sky reflected in water.

I can bring death but also life

> Water can drown people, but is also necessary for life.

Achilles' mother used my kind

> Achilles' mother dipped him into water, while holding him by the heel.

My bed is smooth as sand itself

> There is sand at the bottom of an ocean.

I can be kind and allow you to pass

> If the water is calm, you can navigate it easily.

When I am angry, you won't make it.

> If the water is rough, your boat may capsize.

Comment: Water is just a bit to general in my opinion

Answer (score 3):

Similar with the other,

> Sea (Ocean)

I look at the sky and my eyes reflect it

> Sea reflected the sky, that's why the color is blue.

I can bring death but also life

> Sea is where the lifeforms begin, but also dangerous.

Achilles' mother used my kind

> Achilles' mother [Thetis is sea-Goddess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thetis)

My bed is smooth as sand itself

> Seabed or ocean floor.

I can be kind and allow you to pass
When I am angry, you won't make it.

> Weather in the sea is unpredictable.

Comment: Also a good answer. 1+ for you

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers are of course correct, it's always fun with these to find other answers that fit.
In this case, you could make a decent argument for:

> the sea-deity Aegaeon.

I look at the sky and my eyes reflect it

> All eyeballs reflect the sky other than those of tunnel-dwellers and the eyeless.

I can bring death but also life

> He's a deity, and rather a powerful one, as well as the inventor of warships. However, he was also responsible (via the intervention of Thetis, Achilles' mother) for resolving the Hekatonkheires with the Olympian pantheon through marriage, bringing peace, and hence life.

Achilles' mother used my kind

> Thetis is the one who made him broker the above deal.

My bed is smooth as sand itself

> Sea gods would sleep on the ocean floor.

I can be kind and allow you to pass When I am angry, you won't make it.

> The gods are fickle.

Comment: This answer works too, and the way that you found a more complex answer is very nice. 1+